# Using Component in <apex:repeat>

Tags: community

I have to create a VisualForce page  which should consists of  10 radio buttons using components. After I select the radio button say (value=2), this selected value is to be store in `Survey__c` custom object's field `Recommendation__c` .

Can anyone help me. I have no idea as to how to use component in VisualForce page.

Component from comment:

```
<apex:component >
    <apex:attribute name="record" description="Ratings been given for survey."
            type="Object" required="true"/>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>1</span>
    <div class="row">
        <span>
            <input type="radio" name = "rate" onclick="sendVal(this);" value= "2"/>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="radio" name = "rate" onclick="sendVal(this);" value= "1"/>
        </span>
    </div>
    </div>
</apex:component>
```

Page from comment:

```
<div class="questions">
    How likely are you to recommend a visit as part of a sales strategy to other
    salespeople?
</div>
<div class="rowDiv"></div>
<c:DefaultSurveyRadioButton />
<apex:repeat value="{!plist}" var="speaker" id="speaker_Name1">
    <c:SurveyRadioButton record="rating2"/>
    <apex:outputText value="{!speaker.Presenter__r.Speaker_First_Name__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!s1.Recommendation_Strategy__c}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your requirements in more detail?

Comment: Click the edit link and update the post with your code, you no need to put your code in comments